# Response.Write and Response.End are not working in Codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to prevent the page from loading if the criteria for an if statement isn't met like so (this is my Default.aspx.cs file):

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] splitStaffNo = User.Identity.Name.Split(new string[] { "\\" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

        int StaffNo = Int32.Parse(splitStaffNo[1]);

        if (StaffNo < 249000 || StaffNo > 250000)
        {
            Response.Write "Sorry, you do not have access to this page.";
            Response.End;
        }
    }
```

However, I get an error saying 'Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await and new object expressions can be used as a statement.

I've also tried using `this.Response.Write` and `context.Response.Write` with no luck.

Any idea as to what I'm doing wrong please?

**(edit) I feel silly for asking this now, thank you all so much for the answers though.**

Thank you

Comment: Oh come on.. What do you think what are `Response.Write` and `Response.End`?

Comment: One check if the `StaffNo` is about 249000 is enough! No need to doublecheck, if its over 250000 it also has to be over 249000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like this.You have missed brackets..

This is a syntax for `HttpResponse.Write`

```
void HttpResponse.Write(String s)
```

---

```
 Response.Write ("Sorry, you do not have access to this page.");
 Response.End();
```

Comment: Thank you very much Nagaraj, and sorry for the stupid question.

Comment: @nick you are welcome.And also `StaffNo > 249000` is enough as @datraj said in comment..

Answer (score 1):

`Response.End` and `Response.Write` are functions so you need brackets:

```
Response.Write("Some text here");
Response.End();
```

Comment: Thank you very much David, I was looking at uses of these functions and I think it was all classic ASP :) Requiring brackets makes perfect sense, sorry for the stupid question.

Answer (score 1):

Well, **Response.End** is a function which need bracket. So It should be like this -

```
if (StaffNo > 249000 || StaffNo > 250000)
        {
            Response.Write("Sorry, you do not have access to this page.");
            Response.End();
        }
```

Comment: Makes perfect sense when I see it put like this, sorry for the stupid question! Thank you.